# How to stop multiple port access attempts - multiple TIME_WAIT and ESTABLISHED lines on ports 80, 443, etc... from external IPs

Tags: apache, nginx

I have nginx as reverse proxy and apache in the back, a firewall setup to enable just http and https, and ssh.

netstat -tlupna gives me tens of lines with multiple TIME_WAIT or ESTABLISHED lines coming from plenty of IPs:80 and IPs:443 into my server.

There were few ESTABLISHED connections to ports on my server that I did not recognize.
I assumed the firewall took care of these? So how come there is an established connection from an external IP to a port that I have not opened? Is this suspicious?

How can I stop these attempts to access all my ports?

```
netstat -tlupna
```

tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:57354    zzz.abc.239.34:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:36234    zzz.xyz.108.108:80      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:37014    xxx.abc.120.90:443        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:48508    xxx.xyz.40.40:443       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:40396    xxx.abc.23.31:443       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:35614    xxx.xyz.151.18:80         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:37828    xxx.abc.101.102:443      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:42258    xxx.xyz.64.171:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:12346    xxx.abc.160.70:443      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:12345    xxx.xyz.16.132:443      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:xxx    xxx.abc.xxx.xxx:443       ESTABLISHED xxx/nginx: worker [

tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:37702    xxx.xyz.181.15:443       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:52380    xxx.abc.97.16:80         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:37032    xxx.xyz.120.90:443        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:54220    xxx.abc.dc.123:80       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 MY_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:33324    xxx.abc.ab.123:443      TIME_WAIT   -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I stop these attempts to access all my ports?

These are not attempts to access your ports. These are connections **originating from your system** to remote servers.

It is nothing known about your system setup. But given that at least one of the entries seems to originate from nginx (or at least a process claiming to be nginx) it might be that your system is configured as an open proxy, i.e. allowing others to use your system to access arbitrary servers while hiding their original source IP. But again, due to missing information this is just speculation.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I have nothing else on that server than nginx and apache servers and sshd. The webpage only points to one html files with helloworld on display. I am learning the setup process at the moment. How do I know if my nginx is acting as an open proxy?

Comment: @myke: Try to use it as a proxy, i.e. something like `curl -x proxy_ip:proxy_port http://example.com`

Comment: I tried it - I get the TIME_WAIT line only when I enter proxy_ip:443 http://example.com. or proxy_ip:80 http://example.com.
I get no other outputs when I try the other ports that were listed. 54220, etc...
The reverse proxy is on the same machine as apache.

Comment: @myke: *"I get the TIME_WAIT line only when I enter proxy_ip:443 example.com. or proxy_ip:80 example.com."* - Looks like your nginx is configured as an open proxy based on this description.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any suggestion/links for hardening my reverse proxy and making it a closed proxy? None of my searches address the closed proxy setup. This is for Centos7

Comment: any good resource I can use to familiarize with this topic?

Comment: @myke: *"any good resource I can use to familiarize with this topic?"* - *this topic* is very broad. It includes understanding what the output from netstat even means (which might need a basic understanding of how TCP/IP works) and how to configure nginx. I doubt there is a single good resource which contains all of this in an easy way. This is more like asking if there is a good resource on how to do arbitrary computer related things.

Comment: These topics are good starting points. I know not much about neither...still very green on tcp/ip and nginx. I'll start digging then. cheers!